# The merge process could not connect to the Publisher ' '. Check to ensure that the server is running. (

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

I have 2 servers with 2 kinds of replications between them.
One is Transactional and the other is merge.

The Transactional replication is working fine but in the merge replication, I'm getting error messages.

Error messages:

> The merge process could not connect to the Publisher ' '. Check to
>   ensure that the server is running. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number:
>   MSSQL_REPL-2147198719) Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL-2147198719 The
>   process could not connect to Publisher ' '. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error
>   number: MSSQL_REPL20084) Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL20084 Login
>   failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with
>   Windows authentication. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 18452) Get
>   help: http://help/18452

Two weeks ago everything was working fine (we didn't change anything and they didn't change as well).

I've read and check that the user is db_owner.
Telnet is open (and the transactional replication is working) so there are not any network problems.
I deleted and recreated both replications.

when I'm looking at the publisher server events log I see the error

> SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x80090301, state 14 while
>   establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has
>   been closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. The Windows error
>   code indicates the cause of failure.

Any ideas?

Comment: Few things to check - service account and account used by replication agent are active, error says untrusted domain - so clearly things have changed at network level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i did two things, i dont know which one fixed the problem.
After i check that the user password not expired and not locked out, the connection is good and everything i already mentioned.

1. secpol.msc -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assigments i added the user to access the computer from the internet and Enable computer and user accounts to be trusted for delegation.
2. windows update.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is stated plainly:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication

Try logging in to your Publisher as the replication agent account running on the subscriber (connecting from the subscriber through SSMS). There could have been changes to domain trusts, changes to domain membership, broken SPNs etc that could be causing this.

Validate your domains have a trust between them, your SPNs are configured correctly and that your replication accounts can actually log in to each instance. Also, double check that the accounts themselves are not disabled and\or have expired passwords.

Comment: I cannot apply trust domain between the server, therefore, I use the solution creating local machine account user with the same pass on both servers.